# TIME Parameter for TMS Request

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, tile-map-service

I have a layer in Geoserver that is Time enabled. Using GWC with a `TIME` Parameter filter works great for WMTS and WMS-C. But unfortunately sending a `TIME` Filter with a TMS request like:

`http://localhost/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/test001:test001@EPSG%3A3857@png/20/543538/678041.png?TIME=2017-10-18`

doesn't work (I always get the data for the newest time stamp - TIME is ignored) while the same WMTS request

`http://localhost/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?TIME=2017-10-18&layer=test001%3Atest001&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image%2Fpng&TileMatrix=EPSG%3A3857%3A20&TileCol=543538&TileRow=370534`

works as expected and sends the data for 2017-10-18.

Comment: TMS specification https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification does not mention time. Do you know if GWC supports TMS + time as a vendor option?

Comment: That's actually something I want to find out (and if geoserver supports it). In the docs https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/printing/protocol.html#tms it says "customParams (Optional) Map, additional URL arguments" - so I thought maybe the TIME parameter is available.

Comment: Should have looked more closely... the docs I posted are for the printing plugin. I guess there is not TIME parameter for TMS